# Over cooking shiitake mushrooms?

Tags: asian-cuisine, mushrooms

I eat Asian cuisine a lot but I've started to use shiitake mushrooms in the stead of just about anything else because I think they're delicious.  I've had them in vinaigrettes, caramelizing with onions and outside of the stem (which I only use to flavors stocks and such and then throw away) I don't think I've ever had an overcooked shiitake.  Is there such a thing?  How does the taste change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen pot roast of Shitake. Pot roast = over-cooked obviously.

There were pot roast for: duck roast, chicken roast, pork trotters, buddhist faux meat, Buddha jumped over the wall roast. All of them amply roasted with shitakes.

Okay, for what I have tried, I encountered two kinds of shitake pot roast

- sweet and sour
- sweet and salted soy-sauced

**The Buddhist faux meat**:

I saw the usual buddhist faux meat the permutations of which I think are due to diverse combination of various flours, soy and other beans. The thick gravy is dark brown with obvious scent of dark sweet soy sauce and black vinegar. And the over-cooked shitakes are chewy juicy with the wonderful gravy.

**Chicken pot roast**:

Then there was another time, the chicken pot roast. The gravy was thinner but not sour. It was a whole chicken that was boiled in sauce with the shitake. From what I understand, the shitake roast was done first and then the chicken submerged in the boiling cauldron at the end of the roast. At the last 10 minutes may be. Shitake juiced up with gravy enriched with chicken taste/flavour.

**Chewing on the shitake**

You should try overcooked shitake that has absorbed the juicy gravies. Chocolate mousse cake is nowhere in comparison just as you sink your teeth into it and the juice runs down your chin. And then you lick your fingers after you had them wipe your chin.

Slow cooked shitake pot roast. I am sure there were spices involved. I also believe they used shitakes that had been stabilised by drying (i.e. dried shitakes). Otherwise, I doubt fresh shitakes could take the strain of being overcooked.

Comment: interesting.  i've got tons of fresh shiitakes so i've never used them in their dried form but i do here that they take on some new flavors; i'll have to try that.